# Dealing with missing month values in dataset and plotting a time series

Tags: r, time-series

So i currently have a dataset in R:

```
Date            Mean_Value

2003-10-01      7.94
2004-02-01      3.17
2004-03-01      4.62
2004-04-01      5.38
2004-05-01      4.17
2004-06-01      6.40
2004-07-01      4.12
2004-08-01      3.09
2005-01-01      5.32
.
.
```

and I'm planning to **plot a time series** for the above dataset, but one thing I'm concerned with is that is it the right thing to do, to just plot the time series even though there are **some months of the year** in the dataset above **missing?** for example, in the year **2003**, the missing months are **"November" and "December"** while in the year **2004**, the months missing are **"September,October,November and December"**.

The year list goes on until 2012, and there are indeed **some years with all months present**. Although some years are missing certain months like the example above, would i still be able to plot the time series, ignoring the fact that there **exist missing months** in some years?

Comment: Why couldn't you plot them? Just be sure the date column is translated to an appropriate "X" value rather than the contiguous sequence value. You see TS with big gaps all the time. R-tists sometimes like to drop the point character for intermittent missing values and break the trend-line entirely for large missing gaps. That could be a nice hybrid approach.

Answer (score -2):

you can interpolate in order to estimate the missing values. Time series analysis requires that there are NO MISSING VALUES.  https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about plotting, and not about time series analysis.  There is no reason that a time series can't be plotted when there are missing values.  The values can simply be left out (or perhaps marked on the plot if it is really important for the viewer to realize that there are missing values).

Comment: Interpolation = mean imputation = conservative standard errors. Better to estimate probability model for response and perform a several imputations, combine with Rubin's Rules.

Comment: @dante plotting time series and examining the plot is (to me ) a primitive form of time series analysis.

Comment: @IrishStat I can understand that.  But it still doesn't seem strictly necessary to impute missing value for a plot.  Especially since this sounds like a fairly small data set (120 values, maybe?), imputed points could be misleading.  I would think that imputing missing values would only be useful/important if the analyst desires to make inferences from a time series model.  The human eye is usually pretty good at understanding missing values, assuming the plot is well-constructed.

Comment: agreed .. clearly the OP is new to time series and I was just trying to guide him to " the shining city on the hill" a natural consequence of a visual examination/presentation